# Can't Add Localization in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store-connect

I have a question about iTunes Connect: When I click "Manage Localizations" on the page of my iPhone app (which is online, not in Review or something), I am not able to add a new language.

Does anyone know whether you can only add localizations when creating a new version of the app? Or did I overlook something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

does it say this?

> You cannot add a new language from this page because your app has either **already been approved** or **is currently in review**. To add a new language, you must submit a new version of your app.

So if online means "in the app store" then yes, a new localization is only possible when you submit your next version.